# keydown event not fired while mouse dragging in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, drag, keydown

I noticed a strange behavior regarding keydown event in Chrome.

I have this simple script (http://jsfiddle.net/xYDbt/1/):

```
<div id="x"></div>
<script>
    document.onkeydown = function (e)
    {
        document.getElementById("x").innerHTML += "Hi";
    }
</script>
```

In Chrome, the event is not fired if the mouse is moved around with left click pressed.
This happens *only the first time after loading the page*. Subsequent keypresses work correctly.

I tested this in FF/Opera/IE and it's not a problem.

Is there a workaround for Chrome?

Comment: I'm using Chrome with Mac OS X, and I don't seem to have the problem.

Comment: I **can** replicate it on Windows. It doesn't appear limited to the first attempt after page load - the first keydown event will be ignored for each drag session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst onkeydown and onkeypress are affected by this bug, it appears **onkeyup** is not.

Hope you can workaround with that!

Comment: Thanks, I got around this by returning false in the onmousedown handler, but this could work just as well.

Comment: onkeydown, onkeyup are not wokring during drag for me :/ (Version 37.0.2062.120 Ubuntu 14.04 (281580) (64-bit))